# Experiencing lag when switching UIImageView to another image, how to pre-allocate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, memory, uiimageview

In Xcode, I have 7 background images of different colour that cycle through every time you get another 10 points in the game.

However on the first time of playing the game when it gets to changing the background it lags as it needs to allocate it to memory and then load it.

How can I assign all of these images to load into memory before the level begins, so that it can simply switch to the memory and have no lag.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the backgrounds into an NSCache, its used like a NSDictionary.

```
NSCache *cache = [NSCache new]; // You should ivar this somewhere
```

Then create a method like

```
-(UIImage *)loadImageWithKey:(NSString *)key {
  UIImage *image = [cache objectForKey:key];
  if (image == nil) {
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:key];
    [cache setObject:image forKey:key];
  }
  return image;
}
```

This will let your game be lean, if you run into memory problems, it'll drop everything inside the cache, so your game will be a bit slow if it drops the cache, but you won't crash on memory issues.

Then all you do is on your loading screen call loadImageWithKey: with whatever resources and when requiring it on changing backgrounds call it again there and use the return UIImage.

If you still have problems loading, you'll need to keep your backgrounds smaller or build against something that's more performant for games, SpriteKit, SceneKit, Unity3D etc.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by ivar?

Comment: Instance variable the @property (nonatomic, strong) NSCache *cache;